# Should we use ad units alone for Android and IOS?

Tags: android, ios, admob, google-dfp, ads

We are implementing the Pre-roll video ads, banner, and Interstitial ads Should we use ad units alone for Android and IOS? If we create the separate Ad units for both platforms then Will anything benefits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a lot of time to get the answer to this question, and the result is that it's possible.

Yes, In **DFP** we can create the separate ad units for both platforms, If we maintain the separate id's to both platforms, we can able to see stats for separately.